# Tic-Tac-Toe Function to "switch" player turn allowing new input to be printed

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am writing a Tic-Tac-Toe program. I have gotten to the point of the user typing in a coordinate as a way to play (I have used lists to represent the board however, It only worked for one player i.e. "X" would be inputted into any box and never "O". I have recently tried changing my code to incorporate the second player as well. I have tried to iterate through a list of start options and deleting indexes to select the correct player dependant on the "second_x" variable being either True or False. All I am trying to accomplish is to switch from "X" to "O" every input, but I cannot for the life figure out why it won't switch. Try to ignore the global and return statements everywhere I tried them for the sake of trying to make the problem simpler to solve.

In the codes current state the input is not being processed in the way I thought it would have. It will not print the player's move in the new amended board. I suspect it has something to do with the if statement under both X's and O's moves (commented red in player_moves()). I have also tried itertools cycle but was unable to make that work. If anyone is able to shed any light on this problem I have encountered I would very much appreciate it. I'm sorry for not using a minimal format, I only included the full code to give you the entire context as I may have overlooked something.

Many thanks,

B

```
import random


# displaying the board
board_y0 = ["|", "|", "|"]
board_y1 = ["|", "|", "|"]
board_y2 = ["|", "|", "|"]
board_axisy = ["Y-1", "Y-2", "Y-3"]
board_axisx = [" X-1 ", "X-2 ", "X-3"]
game=True
start_options = ["X", "O"]
current = []
X = 0


def start_player():
    global first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x, start_options
    # deciding who starts first
    player1 = f"{start_options[0]}"
    player2 = f"{start_options[1]}"
    first_move = random.choice(start_options)
    if first_move == player2:
        second_x = True
    else:
        second_x = False
    if first_move == "X":
        print(player1, "starts first. ")
    elif first_move == "O":
        print(player2, "starts first. ")
    try:
        return first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x, start_options
    finally:
        board_display()


def board_display():
    global first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x, start_options
    print(board_y0, board_axisy[2])
    print(board_y1, board_axisy[1])
    print(board_y2, board_axisy[0])
    print(board_axisx[0], board_axisx[1], board_axisx[2])
    # new values of lists passed to function
    try:
        game = True
        return first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x
    finally:
        player_moves()


def player_moves():
    global first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x, start_options
    if game == True:
        move = int(input("Choose a coordinate, i.e. 12 format: "))
                    
        # X's moves
        if current == "X":
            # Y1 axis
            if move == 11 and second_x == False:
                board_y2[0] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 12 and second_x == False:
                board_y2[1] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 13 and second_x == False:
                board_y2[2] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            # Y2 axis
            if move == 21 and second_x == False:
                board_y1[0] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 22 and second_x == False:
                board_y1[1] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 23 and second_x == False:
                board_y1[2] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            # Y3 axis
            if move == 31 and second_x == False:
                board_y0[0] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 32 and second_x == False:
                board_y0[1] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True
            if move == 33 and second_x == False:
                board_y0[2] = "X"
                if second_x == False:
                    second_x = True

            # O's moves
        if current == "O":
            # Y1 axis
            if move == 11 and second_x == True:
                board_y2[0] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            if move == 12 and second_x == True:
                board_y2[1] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            if move == 13 and second_x == True:
                board_y2[2] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            # Y2 axis
            if move == 21 and second_x == True:
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
                board_y1[0] = "O"
            if move == 22 and second_x == True:
                board_y1[1] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            if move == 23 and second_x == True:
                board_y1[2] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            # Y3 axis
            if move == 31 and second_x == True:
                board_y0[0] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            if move == 32 and second_x == True:
                board_y0[1] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False
            if move == 33 and second_x == True:
                board_y0[2] = "O"
                if second_x == True:
                    second_x = False

            # breaking loop, returning values to print board
            try:
                game = False
                return first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x
            finally:
                player_turn_switch()


def player_turn_switch():
    global first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2, second_x, start_options, X
    # cycling through list and deleting correct item to allow players turns to switch
    for i in range(len(start_options)):
        current.append(start_options[X % len(start_options)])
        X += 1
        print(current)
    if second_x == False:  # O chosen to go next
        del current[0]
    print(current)
    if second_x == True:  # X chosen to go next
        del current[1]

    try:      
        return current, X, second_x, first_move, player1, player2, game, board_y0, board_y1, board_y2
        X = 0
    finally:
        board_display()


start_player()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your players in the list `["X", "Y"]` you can switch between them by reversing the list and getting first element. Also, small suggestions:

- avoid using globals
- define constants in upper case
- keep your board as a single multiline string
- keep available turns (as well as its coordinates on the board) in the dict

Take a look at the following example:

```
import random

PLAYERS = ['X', 'O']
TURNS = {'A1': 35, 'A2': 39, 'A3': 43, 'B1': 67, 'B2': 71, 'B3': 75, 'C1': 107, 'C2': 103, 'C3': 107}
BOARD = '''
    1   2   3
  |---|---|---|
A |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
B |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
C |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
'''


random.shuffle(PLAYERS)
while True:
    print(BOARD)
    while True:
        turn = input(f'"{PLAYERS[0]}" turn. Choose a coordinate (i.e. "A1"): ').upper()
        if turn in list(TURNS.keys()):
            index = TURNS[turn]
            BOARD = BOARD[:index] + PLAYERS[0] + BOARD[index+1:]
            PLAYERS.reverse()  # switch players
            del TURNS[turn]
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrect coordinate!')
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3
  |---|---|---|
A |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
B |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
C |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|

"O" turn. Choose a coordinate (i.e. "A1"): A2

    1   2   3
  |---|---|---|
A |   | O |   |
  |---|---|---|
B |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
C |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|

"X" turn. Choose a coordinate (i.e. "A1"): C3

    1   2   3
  |---|---|---|
A |   | O |   |
  |---|---|---|
B |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
C |   |   | X |
  |---|---|---|
```

Comment: this was a very simple solution, how did I forget about the .reverse() method.  Doh. The clarification between global and local scope was very helpful as I am new to coding in general. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. Nor is your code example functional. A couple of quick observations. First, you never need to return global variables as they are already in global scope. Second, if all you want to do is switch players and their respective symbol, there's many ways to skin the rat. One way that comes to mind:

```py
player = 0 # 0 for 'o', 1 for 'x'
symbols = ['o', 'x']

def doTurn():
  ...
  symbol = symbols[player]
  ...
  player ^= 1
  return
```

Comment: _"First, you never need to return global variables as they are already in global scope"_ ...or to look at it the other way around, generally it's a better design to use return values rather than sprinkling global vars everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who replied it really helped me a lot. I removed global vars and all the empty returns as well as the second_x variable and just specified index to choose the players turn.

```
def player_turn_switch(move):
    if move in range(11, 34):
        start_options.reverse()
    else:
        print("Check formatting... ")
        player_moves()
    try:      
        return move
    finally:
        board_display()
```